# Tomcat URL rewriting

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

would like to seek help regarding URL rewriting for Tomcat9.

I've developed an web app using J2EE and MVC framework.

The current URL is for accessing the web is

```
http://www.example.com:8080/MyApp/App/login.html
```

(Login.html is my default index.html)

What I'm hoping to achieve is to get `http://www.example.com:8080/login.html`
    Meaning that for every page, the MyApp/App structure will be hidden from the URL

I've researched on URL rewriting but I'm confused with the regular expressions used. For instance I found the following snippet but am not too sure what the second line RewriteRule means. First line probably means ignore css, img, js files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|img|js|partials|rest|favicon).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using Apache to rewrite the URLs. Why don't you just put login.html at the root of your web app? Who decided that it should be at MyApp/App? I think that maybe MyApp comes from your WAR file, and App is a servlet mount point or something like that, right? You can get rid of the WAR path by naming your file ROOT.WAR, [but there are other methods too](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application). To get rid of App, you can mount your servlet on "/", or (if you framework supports it) use a filter rather than a servlet to serve your requests.

The rewrite rule you included (it's just one rule), says, if the request URL starts with css, img, etc. (the `RewriteCond` regex), then don't do anything (that's what '-' means) and stop evaluating rewrite rules (`[L]` which stands for Last). It doesn't seem very useful for your situation, but this is probably an exclusion: there are other rules after it that we do want to apply, and this one is designed to avoid rewriting a few paths (css, img, etc.) that we want to leave alone.

Comment: Hi, I tried deploying my app as ROOT.war before on my server. However, when i tried to login, the other functions break and i wasn't able to login at all.

Comment: Are there parts of your app that assume that the path will be MyApp/App? If so, those parts will break even if you rewrite the URLs. I recommend getting this to work without URL rewriting, because *unless you really need it* URL rewriting will just add some unwanted extra complexity to your app.

Comment: Yeah actually alot of other pages require the MyApp/App. because theres a function that actually generates a pdf report from the url too. How can i get this to work without URL rewriting?

Comment: You will pretty much have to go through your app and fix the parts that rely on the path being MyApp/App. Making the change in each instance will be simple, might require some effort to find all the affected features though.

Comment: Based on your guide, it mentions deploying the war as ROOT.war. However I have to delete the root folder as well? How do i go about doing that in the server? Assuming im running CentOS 6 VPS

Comment: What does "delete the root folder" mean?

Comment: According to the link you provided above, it mentioned... "The first option is very straightforward: we just have to delete the default /ROOT/ folder in $CATALINA_HOME\webapps, rename our ExampleApp.war to ROOT.war, and deploy it."